# Dynamic Real-Time Animation Sync in Unity - Seeking Guidance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm working on a unique interactive dancing rhythm game in Unity where the primary focus is on the synchronization between two character models during their interactions. WThe characters' movements are not pre-determined, as the game requires real-time adjustments based on player input and AI-driven reactions.

**The Challenge**:

When a player character initiates a rhythmic point (visually, stepping out his left foot, for example), the other character has the choice to follow or not. It is allowed not to follow at all, and, if they do decide to follow, their actual input timing is going to be realistically reflected in the animation. So depending on how late their input is in relation to that of the first player character, the animation should look different.

It's all simple and easy if you're thinking as the second player character, because you know when the first input is, but what about the first player character? When you first input, you don't know whether your dancing partner is going to respond or not, and, if they do decide to respond, you don't know how late their inputs are. So, without knowing those information, you don't know what animations to play for the first player, because the animations are dependent on both player character inputs (aka, the time difference between the first player and the second player).

What made it even harder is that depending on how late you are, the animations look really different. Like if both players sync in timing, the animation looks in one way, but if both players failed to sync, then the animation could look really different.

Essentially, the core challenge is this: I want to create an animation system that can choose and play different animations depending on future variables.

**What I've Tried**:

Knowing it is impossible to predict a not-yet-happened input from another player, and knowing that the animation is depending on this future input, I tried "blending" between different animations with Unity Blendtree.

To be specific, I created 3 animations, each representing a scenario:

1. *Sync*: The other player input with a slight time difference, but within the time window.
2. *Late*: The other player input with a significant time difference, but within the time window.
3. *No-follow-inputs*: Within the time window of 2 seconds, there is no second input from another player

My method is that when the first player initiates their input, this character will play the Sync anim first, regardless of the second input. As the time difference increases and reaches a threshold, the sync anim will blend into the late anim, then the no-follow-inputs anim. However, the actual results are horrible, because these 3 animations are visually different. And to transition between them within 2 seconds... well it is just bad.

**My Goals**:

1. Achieve seamless real-time synchronization between two interacting character animations that depend on both players' inputs.
2. Ensure accurate translation and functioning of the Blender model bone structure in Unity.
3. Handle unpredictable character movement timings, necessitating dynamic animation adjustments.

Does anyone have experience with similar challenges or any recommendations on how to address these issues? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or advice on potential solutions or alternative approaches.

Thank you in advance!